# Change value of character pointed by a pointer

Tags: c, string-literals

I would like to know why my code giving me error when run.

I am trying to change the character value pointed by a pointer variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char amessage[] = "foo";
  char *pmessage = "foo";

  // try 1
  amessage[0] = 'o'; // change the first character to '0'
  printf("%s\n", amessage);

  // try 2
  *pmessage = 'o'; // This one does not work
  printf("%s\n", pmessage);
}
```

The first attempt works, and prints `ooo`. But the second one gives me:

```
[1]    9677 bus error  ./a.out
```

Any ideas?

Comment: arrays and pointers are not the same thing in C

Comment: Thanks @GovindParmar. Downvoters: Please explain how I can improve this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement

```
*pmessage = 'o';
```

you are trying to change the string literal `"foo"` because the pointer is defined like

```
char *pmessage = "foo";
```

String literals are immutable in C and C++. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Could you confirm that, according to your answer, this line of code is not valid in the current C standard? https://github.com/ccpalettes/the-c-programming-language-second-edition-solutions/blob/master/Chapter5/Exercise%205-05/strncpy.c#L25

Comment: @SungWonCho The line in the sample you referenced is correct because the string literal itself is not changed there.

Comment: @SungWonCho There is another problem. The memory where the string literal is copied was not allocated. So the code has undefined behavior. The pointer s declared like char *s; has indeterminate value.

Comment: @SungWonCho For example s could be declared as an array of 9 characters. For example char s[9]; In this case the program would be valid.

Comment: The second point makes sense. But doesn't `(*s++ = *t++)` change the string literal `s`?

Comment: @SungWonCho Ther is the memory pointed to by s is changed that results in undefined behavior because the pointer is not initialized by a valid address. A for the string literal then it is just copied.